# Parsing SOAP response using libxml in Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, xmp

I am trying to parse following SOAP response coming from Savon SOAP api

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getConnectionResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservice.jchem.chemaxon">
            <ns:return>
                <ConnectionHandlerId>connectionHandlerID-283854719</ConnectionHandlerId>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:getConnectionResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to use libxml-ruby without any success. Basically I want to extract anything inside  tag and the connectionHandlerID value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using Savon you can convert the response to a hash. The conversion method `response.to_hash` does some other useful things for you as well.

You would then be able to get the value you want using code similar to the following

```
hres = soap_response.to_hash
conn_handler_id = hres[:get_connection_response][:return][:connection_handler_id]
```

Check out the [documentation](http://savon.rubiii.com/docs/0.7.6/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Assuming your XML response is in an object named response.

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML::parse response
doc.at_xpath("//ConnectionHandlerId").text
```

Comment: thanks Crudson, I am looking on nokogiri. But there are some nokogiri issues with JRuby which I am currently using.